# replace wordpress directory by index

Tags: wordpress, directory

I install wordpress under a sub directory. and now I want it too display in my headdirectory. I found out how if the url is something like this

http://www.sitename.nl/worpress but I have it installed like this http://worpress.sitename.nl/
What is the right path for: require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

Answer (score 0):

Go in Settings > General on Admin Panel in Wordpress.

Change the details to:

```
Wordpress address (url) http://www.sitename.nl/worpress    
Site Address (url)  http://worpress.sitename.nl/
```

or edit on index.php

```
require( dirname( FILE ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```